# iterate through previously filtered rows openpyxl

Tags: python, vba, excel, openpyxl

I have a python code written that loads an excel workbook, iterates through all of the rows in a specified column, saves the rows in a dictionary and writes that dictionary to a .txt file.

The vb script that is referenced opens the workbook before openpyxl does and filters it to only show some data.

The only problem is that when openpyxl iterates through the workbook, it records every value instead of the filtered data.

for example if the original spreadsheet is:

```
   A   B   C
1  x   x   x
2  x   y   x
3  x   x   x
```

and I filter column B to only show rows that contain "x", then save the workbook. I want openpyxl to only iterate through rows 1 and 3.

here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import workbook
import os
#sort using vba script
os.system(r"C:\script.vbs")

#load workbook
path = 'C:/public/temp/workbook.xlsm'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')
#make empty lists
proj_name = []
proj_num = []
proj_status = []

#iterate through rows and append values to lists
for row in ws.iter_rows('D{}:D{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        proj_name.append(cell.value)

for row in ws.iter_rows('R{}:R{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        proj_num.append(cell.value)

for row in ws.iter_rows('G{}:G{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        proj_status.append(cell.value)

#create dictionary from lists using defaultdict
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = dict((z[0],list(z[1:])) for z in zip(proj_num,proj_name,proj_status))

with open(r"C:\public\list2.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(dict1))
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: openpyxl works with the file format, VBA works with Excel the application: these are not the same thing. You'll need to write your own filter for openpyxl. Looping through the worksheet multiple times is also pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `openpyxl` does not currently include filtering in its functionality. As [the documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/filters.html#using-filters-and-sorts) notes: "Filters and sorts can only be configured by openpyxl but will need to be applied in applications like Excel."

It looks as though you may have to find another solution ...

Comment: That is unfortunate, thank you for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

f is the data I want to filter: (e.g. 'CISCO' only with(and)'PAI'  or  'BD' only with(and) 'PAP'  or  'H' is 42 )

```
f = {
    'C': ["CISCO", "BD"],
    'E': ["PAI", "PAP"],
    'H': [60]
```

}

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string

def filter_data(rows, f_config, skip_header=False):
        # convert column alphabet string to index number (e.g. A=1, B=2)
        new_config = {}
        for col, fil in f_config.items():
            if type(col) == str:
                col = column_index_from_string(col)
            new_config[col] = fil

    output = []
    t_filter = len(new_config.items())
    for n, row in enumerate(rows):
        if n == 0:
            if skip_header == True:
                # first row header
                continue
        for i, (col,fil) in enumerate(new_config.items()):
            if type(fil) != list:
                fil = [fil]
            val = row[col-1].value
            # break the loop if any of the conditions not meet
            if not val in fil:
                break
            if i+1 == t_filter:
                # all conditions were met, add into output
                output.append(row)
    return output

#flexible to edit/filter which column of data you want
data1 = filter_data(sheet.rows, { "C": "CISCO", "E": "PAI" }, skip_header=True)

#filter 2 possibility, either str or value
data2 = filter_data(data1, { "H": [ "60", 60 ] } )
```